# WPF Grid Control, pivot child data

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, pivot

Is there an effective control or method whereby I could bind a grid to a datasource, and the grid could (for lack of a better word) "pivot" a property which contains a collection to display on the same row as the parent?

Example:  Datasource object has 3 properties, Name, Status, and StatusDateCollection.

StatusDateCollection could contain any number of items.

I want to bind to a grid which would display something like:

Test 1     Active     1/1/2016  2/1/2016  3/1/2016
Test 2     Inactive   7/1/2016  8/1/2016
Test 3     Suspended  3/1/2015  4/1/2015  5/1/2015  6/1/2015  7/1/2015

Do any of the popular grid controls (Telerik, Infragistics, Syncfusion, etc.) provide a way to do this?

Comment: Is using Google so hard? [First match](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/pivotgrid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Xceed WPF DataGrid, Cell templates can be defined as anyway you like. I'm sure any WPF datagrid enables this in someway. So you can define a cell template for that column, where the template will display the collection data in anyway you want.